# can chef lwrp return the answer as variable (false or true) for later use in a recipe?

Tags: chef-infra, lwrp

So the question is simple. Can I get the answer if my lwrp did the change as false or true? I know that it's visible in Chef Logs, but my idea is to use the results later in a recipe code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, resources do not have "output" values. That said, you can do something like store a value in `node.run_state[:foo]` which is a global hash visible from all levels of the converge. There is a reason that mutable global values are a cliche though, they really are terrible to maintain.

Comment: Thanks. I can see only one way as well - node attribute. My function is to check if files are in use. So I expect to get the output. Is it possible to put this under definition or something else to avoid code duplication. Or what is the best solution?

Comment: You should make a library helper method, not a resource.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to use the library helper in `not_if` or `only_if` guards, is it possible to pass the parameter(file names) into it? So basically, I want to pass the parameters-strings and get the output true or false.

Comment: Sure, make it a parameter to your method just like any other Ruby code.